# Dreamweaver CC - Code View Font Type

Tags: fonts, settings, dreamweaver, code-view

I had Dreamweaver CC, test version, now I have CS6. I really liked the default settings of the code view (font type, background color etc.) in CC. Now I uninstalled CC and I am stuck with the sloppy CS6 code view. So, could you just open your Dreamweaver CC and check the default:

font of the code view? 
background color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked it out and the font is [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) at 10pt (small)

And here is the color for the default "Classic"

[image]